# Почему я не могу вызвать overridePendingTransition() внутри RecyclerView.ViewHolder.setOnClickListener?

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview

В методе `onBindViewHolder` я могу вызвать `startActivity`, но не могу `overridePendingTransition`.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(holder.itemView.context, QuoteSelected::class.java)
            holder.itemView.context.startActivity(intent)
            //overridePendingTransition(anim1, anim2) -> unresolved reference
        }
    }
```

И как иначе я могу вызвать анимацию перехода?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один из вариантов - передать активность откуда вы работаете в адаптер и вызывать через нее этот метод:

```
mActivity.overridePendingTransition()
```

второй вариант - вытаскивать получить активность из контекста:

```
((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left)
```

[вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31110275/overridependingtransition-method-in-adapter-in-android) описан полный вариант открытия активности из адаптера.